# Restart List Numbering for Word Doc from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a spreadsheet which has a matrix, with text in the first column that gets implemented into a built Word document if there is an "X" in the cell in the same row as that line of text. From this, I make lists with headings, but am having trouble restarting the list after every heading.

Below is my code that attempts to restart the list. It returns no errors until the last line item before the End If (List Galleries). Can anyone help?

```
                If Range("A" & X - 1).Value = "Heading" Then
                        With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
                            .NumberFormat = "(%1)"
                            .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
                            .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleLowercaseLetter
                            .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2)
                            .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
                            .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(2.63)
                            .TabPosition = wdUndefined
                            .ResetOnHigher = 0
                            .StartAt = 1
                            With .Font
                                .Bold = wdUndefined
                                .Italic = wdUndefined
                                .Strikethrough = wdUndefined
                                .Subscript = wdUndefined
                                .Superscript = wdUndefined
                                .Shadow = wdUndefined
                                .Outline = wdUndefined
                                .Emboss = wdUndefined
                                .Engrave = wdUndefined
                                .Allcaps = wdUndefined
                                .Hidden = wdUndefined
                                .Underline = wdUndefined
                                .Color = wdColorBlack
                                .Size = wdUndefined
                                .Animation = wdUndefined
                                .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
                                .Name = ""
                            End With
                            .LinkedStyle = "SOWSubList"
                        End With
                        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
                        objWord.ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select
                        Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
                            ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
                            True, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
                            wdWord10ListBehavior
                End If
                objWord.Selection.TypeParagraph 'move to the next line
```

Comment: No, SOWSubList is a custom style that I use in the Word file!

Comment: What error do you get?